# Policy gradient base line function

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives, machine-learning

On the bottom of page ten of the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00909.pdf) on probabilistic reinforcement learning, there are 3 equations where is author manipulates the policy gradient $\nabla_\theta J(\theta)$.

Can someone please explain to me how to derive the last (third) line from the previous (second) line?

I feel like we have to prove either one of those expressions: But I don't know how to go about it.

$$
\nabla_\theta log\  q_\theta (a_t|s_t) (\sum_{t'=t}^T b(s_{t'})) = 0
$$
or 
$$
E_{(s_t,a_t) ~ q(s_t,a_t)}[\nabla_\theta log\  q_\theta (a_t|s_t) (\sum_{t'=t}^T b(s_{t'}))] = 0
$$

Thanks for reading.